# How to set auto layout on all iOS devices?

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints, ios-autolayout

So basically I have this problem where all my auto layout constraints look fine on all devices except iPhone 5s and SE. Also, the constraints look different for iPad devices but are generally the same. How do I have it so that the constraints look the same on all devices??

Below shows iPhone 8 vs iPad Pro

[image: iPhone 8]

[image: iPad Pro]

Comment: Kindly Share your layout screens.

Comment: @RajJoshi I have added the pictures of the difference in layout screens

Comment: You should set 00 label constraints as center horizontal & vertical and hight, width, and min label to set leading and center in vertical with 00 label.

Comment: @RajJoshi why doesn't the font size change accordingly when I switch to an iPad?

Comment: @RajJoshi Will I have to detect the device type and set the font size to change manually or is there a way to do that easily with auto layout and storyboard settings of the item?

Answer (score 1):

What you are discussing is possible, it is called Trait Variation that allows you to set up layouts based on different device dimensions and categories.

Here is a tutorial that discusses it and explains how to use it: 
https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Trait_Variations_to_Design_Adaptive_iOS_User_Interfaces